# Position UI.Button to mouse position

Tags: c#, unity

This has been discussed a couple of times, but I didn't find any solution:

I want to set the position of an UI.Button to my mouse position.
I can get the mouse position like this:

```
Vector3 cameraVector = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

Problem: The UI elements are using another "coordination system". How can I handle that problem?

Answer (score 3):

Input.mousePosition is already in screen coordinates.
You do not need any transfomations, just pass it to [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html).

Here is example of doing it: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/781643/unity-46-beta-rect-transform-position-new-ui-syste.html

Comment: This is not working as expected. The mouse position is different to the position where the button is placed at. Do I need to take any changes at the Canvas?

Comment: I believe you need to adjust button's Rect Transform anchors, pivot and positions or, at least, keep this parameters in mind when moving a button.
Also be sure your canvas mode set to Screen space - Camera, or you will have new parameters to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use Unity's [`RectTransformUtility`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html) with a call to the `ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`. Or `ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle` if you have a World Space UI. Then set the UI `anchoredPosition`.